# Why won't my computer boot after installing my new GTX 1050?

Tags: windows-10, boot, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu

I have this pc (https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02838702) and I installed a Corsair CS-M 550W PSU so I can upgrade the gpu. I bought an EVGA GTX 1050 (not TI) and after installing, the boot screen (with the hp logo) shows up, the computer beeps once, waits a couple seconds, beeps again, and is shortly followed by 3 beeps in rapid succession. When I reinstall my AMD Card, it boots up fine, even though I have no drivers installed. Please help so I can game again :(

I don't know if it matters, but I'm running Windows 10 Home 64-Bit

Comment: What was your previous AMD card? And the model of your HP? Easier to interpret beep codes when you know what the hardware is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motherboard was really old and only supported legacy cards. Ended up just using what I had until I could afford a new PC. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [this link](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1981909/beeps-boot-attempted-graphics-card-install.html)? (found via Google)

> Try to reseat the card and try to reseat the ram too. then take if that does not work take the card out and goto the bois and tell the pc the main graphics will be pcie not the on board. then reinstall the card , and try to reboot a few times with the card in and the new settings , it might take a few try to get it to recognize the new card! 
>   If those dont work you might need to rma the card!

Another possible answer from the link above:

> It ended up being the power connection. I was mistaken in thinking the plug was for crossfire, but if I had stopped to look at the crossfire cord for more than a second, I would have realized that it wasn't true. I just plugged the power supply to the card, and off it went.

Also, if the above steps don't work, try updating the BIOS. If it still doesn't work you should go ahead with RMA.

Comment: Been a while, but figured I might as well reply. My knowledge of computers has grown a lot! Anyways, the problem was that the card was simply incompatible. The motherboard was really old and only supported legacy cards.